# Z-index issue in pop up div

Tags: html, popup, z-index

When i click on a button on my web page want to popoup a div which takes full height and width so any other elements cannot be clicked until the div is closed.

When the div is available I want to click a certain element of the web page only. Tried to give

popup div
     z-index of 10

and the element 
     z-index of 1000 but it didnt work. Plz provide ur sugesstions

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work or you, zindex should only be an issue if you have set it some where else on your page. By using position absolute it will display over everything if there is no z-index clashes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".button").click(function(){
                togglePopUp()
            });

        });
        function togglePopUp(){
            if($(".popUp").is(":visible")){
                $(".popUp").css('display', 'none') ;
            }else{
                $(".popUp").css('display', 'block') ;
            }

        }
</script>
<style>
body{
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
.popup{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#000;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
z-index:10;
}
.close{
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    color:red;
    }



</style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="popUp" style="display: none"><div class="button close">close me</div></div>
    <div class="button">click me</div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Example is [posted here](http://www.dominic-green.com/examples/popup.html)

Comment: What i want is to display a element inside the web page when the popup is already there

Comment: if you can show an example off the page I would be able to more quickly help ;)